# How does one implement asynchronous methods like HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()?

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

If one wants to write asynchronous methods similar to `HttpClient.GetStreamAsync()`, what's the recommended approach?

For instance, is the following approach okay:

```
    static async Task<String> LengthyOperation()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Executing a lengthy operation...");
        Debug.WriteLine("LENGTHY THREAD ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        var task = new Task(() =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("TASK THREAD ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
                {
                    File.ReadAllLines("abc.txt");
                    counter++;
                }
            });

        task.Start();
        return task;
    }
```

Comment: If you want it to run on the same thread, why do you make it a Task? Why don't you just put the code in to the LengthyOperation method (or call the inner content as a regular method call)?

Comment: What is the point of having a task that executes on the same thread as the caller?

Comment: I don't understand: the code inside `task` is completely synchronous and you want to run it on the current thread, so why are you using `Task`s at all? If you want `LengthyOperation()` to be asynchronous, that asynchrony has to come from somewhere: either from running code on another thread, or (much better) from using actually asynchronous operations, like `StreamReader.ReadToEndAsync()` (there are not async operations on `File`).

Comment: @I3arnon If the code in the task contained some `await`s, then executing the synchronous parts on the same thread often makes sense.

Comment: @svick Well, that's what synchronization contexts are for - to ensure the await continuations execute back on the original thread. But not for the tasks themselves, that really makes no sense (apart from some weird cooperative multi-tasking scenario).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to start a task asynchronously, as is done in the asynchronous methods like HttpClient.GetStreamAsync() etc?

Ideally, only naturally-asynchronous methods (such as I/O) expose asynchronous APIs. This is normally done via `Task.Factory.FromAsync` or `TaskCompletionSource<T>`.

E.g:

```
static Task MyOpAsync()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  ... // Establish a callback that calls tcs.TrySetResult when the operation completes
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: Now this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you Stephen! It's a shame though that I can't upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: @Curious If it's exactly what you've been looking for, then you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `TaskScheduler`

sample

```
TaskScheduler scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
task.Start(scheduler); //use the schedular
```

result

```
LENGTHY THREAD ID: 8
TASK THREAD ID: 8
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Sure, it's a bad idea, but it does answer the question.

Comment: @Luaan I am thinking the same, OP asked to invoke the task on the calling thread so that both shows the same ID.

Comment: Thank you for posting results as well. I'll have to try it out myself though :)

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very simple, you need another method though

```
private async Task LongTaskImpl()
{
    Debug.WriteLine("TASK THREAD ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
    {
       File.ReadAllLines("abc.txt");
       counter++;
    }
}    

static async Task LengthyOperation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing a lengthy operation...");
    Debug.WriteLine("LENGTHY THREAD ID: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    var task = LongTaskImpl();
    await task;
}
```

Now you have a task that is running on the same thread as its caller.
However, there is nothing asynchronous in your code, so it will just run synchronously. Just making something into a Task doesn't mean that it magically becomes asynchronous, you have to call (and wait) some asynchronous actions for that).

Comment: Well this seems a good idea. I just have to try it out, thank you. On this being synchronous actually, I'm aware of that. After all it's just a sample code :)